# Looping and printing without messages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I using this loop to print number

```
DECLARE @A Int
SET @A = 33
WHILE @A < 55
BEGIN
SELECT @A as sequence
SET @A = @A + 1
END
GO
```

But problem that with every loop message is printed like example:

```
sequence
-----------
53
```

(1 row(s) affected)

How to print in order like this:

34
35
36
37

Can help me with CTE example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PRINT

```
DECLARE @A INT
SET @A = 33
WHILE @A < 55
BEGIN
PRINT @A
SET @A = @A + 1
END
GO
```

For the CTE you can try

```
DECLARE @A INT,
        @End INT
SET @A = 33
SET @End = 55

;WITH Selected AS (
        SELECT  @A Val
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  Val + 1
        FROM    Selected
        WHERE   Val < @End
)
SELECT *
FROM Selected
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to print the value, you can use [the PRINT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx). If you want to actually return the result (if your code is part of a stored procedure, for example), you could define a temporary [table type variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx), insert data on it on each loop, then return the contents of the table.

Comment: How to run inside CTE and then list all values?